# Meeting "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index" when using jdbcTemplate to execute a SQL statement without argument.

Tags: java, jdbctemplate, sqlexception

I have code like following:

```
public class InspectDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport{
    ...
    public ShiftTime getShiftTime(){
        String sql = "";
        ...//Only for assigning value to sql, it will be seen in exception stack trace. 
        Map<String, Object> map = this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForMap(sql, "oracle");//Error occured here. 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

When I call this method, it post an error as `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index`. 
The main stack trace is this, it includes my SQL statement:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL [
>                   **SELECT * FROM 
>
>                   (SELECT * FROM shifttime ORDER BY id DESC)
>
>                   WHERE rownum = 1**
>           ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

I have search of this exception, but those conditions are all different from my case.

There isn't any placeholder like "?" in my SQL statement, so why can this error occur?

Comment: Can you show us the complete SQL statement?

Comment: @deHaar It's concluded in the exception message and I bolded it up.

Comment: Since you don't seem to use the `"oracle"` argument, could you try `queryForMap(sql)` ?

Comment: is it required to have an alias for subquery in oracle? if yes, makes sense to add one

Comment: Have a look at the statements in the [JavaDocs of the `InvalidResultSetAccessException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/InvalidResultSetAccessException.html), which basically state *This typically happens when an invalid ResultSet column index or name has been specified. Also thrown by disconnected SqlRowSets.*

Comment: @deHaar there is a pseudocolumn called `rownum` in oracle, my bad

Comment: @Arnaud Thank you very much, I tried your advice and it works now.

Comment: @mangusta aaarrggh... Ok, there must be any invalid access anyway...